# Detect sign changes in an array

Tags: python, pandas

I need to put an order when the values change from positive to negative, for example (print "sell"),
and when they change from negative to positive, for example (print "buy").  For indexes where there is not a sign change, I want to print "ok".

How should I code this with python?

---

**Example input**

```
list = [ 1, 2, 6, -3, -2, -5, 6, 7, 1, -1, -3]
```

First three values (1, 2, 6)  are positive values, but when it becomes minus, I want to `print('sell')`

And for -3, -2, -5, there are negative values, when it becomes positive, I want to `print('buy')`

Otherwise, (when the values keep the same sign) `print('ok')`

**Example output**

```
ok ok ok sell ok ok buy ok ok sell ok
```

Comment: We expect your question to be self-contained.  Post the example as part of the question.  Off-site links are not acceptable; images of text are not acceptable.

Comment: @Prune You have an extra space in your comment. Are you familiar with [Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code/286760#286760)? Minimal reproducible examples are useful for debug-Questions, not how-to Questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple code that resolve your problem/exemple:

```
l = [ 1, 2, 6, -3, -2, -5, 6, 7, 1, -1, -3]
for i in range(0, len(l)-1):
    p = l[i] * l[i+1]
    if p > 0:
        print('ok')
    elif l[i+1] < 0:
        print('sell')
    else:
        print('buy')
```

And if you want a new column in your dataframe, this is an example for you:

```
d = {'col1': range(11), 'col2': [ 1, 2, 6, -3, -2, -5, 6, 7, 1, -1, -3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['shift_col'] = df.col2.shift(-1)

df
col1    col2    shift_col
0   0   1   2.0
1   1   2   6.0
2   2   6   -3.0
3   3   -3  -2.0
4   4   -2  -5.0
5   5   -5  6.0
6   6   6   7.0
7   7   7   1.0
8   8   1   -1.0
9   9   -1  -3.0
10  10  -3  NaN
```

and this is a our simple function in the previous example:

```
def compare(line):
    p = line.col2 * line.shift_col
    if p > 0:
        return 'ok'
    elif line.shift_col < 0:
        return 'sell'
    else:
        return 'buy'
        
df['order'] = df.apply(compare, axis=1)
```

Finaly, this will be the result:

```
col1    col2    shift_col   order
0   0   1   2.0 ok
1   1   2   6.0 ok
2   2   6   -3.0    sell
3   3   -3  -2.0    ok
4   4   -2  -5.0    ok
5   5   -5  6.0 buy
6   6   6   7.0 ok
7   7   7   1.0 ok
8   8   1   -1.0    sell
9   9   -1  -3.0    ok
10  10  -3  NaN buy
```

Comment: I think this is what I want, I will check and see the output, thanks

Comment: thanks, your code work great for list, could you help me do same as pandas, https://ibb.co/bmvgtWq check this image please, I want to create new column named by"order", from raw.MACDline

Comment: I edited my response above

Comment: thank you very much ' habibi' , you are really awesome,I just added this line -- df['shift_plus'] = df.order.shift(1) -- to make is exactly.

Comment: can I ask you next days for any problem ? I just start 1 month ago, I am begginer.

Comment: Yes of course ... in any time, you can also start by choosing my response as a valid answer, perhaps it will help someone else ;)

Comment: bro , I have a new question, can you help me for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is a simple boolean you want (True/False) and that is pretty easy to get from a list by converting it to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [ 1, 2, 6, -3, -2, -5, 6, 7, 1, -1, -3] 

my_array = np.array(my_list) # convert list to numpy array

print(my_array >= 0)
```

If you wanted to map the results to specific text you can map it like so:

```
def mapping(n):
    if n:
        return "ok"
    else:
        return "sell"

print(list(map(mapping, my_array >= 0)))
```